# Debugging a Laravel application using Zend Studio breakpoints

Tags: laravel, debugging, breakpoints, zend-studio, laravel-8

I want to use server breakpoints in Zend Studio to debug a Laravel application. However I am unable to find any documentation involving how to set up Zend Studio breakpoints to work with a Laravel application.

[The documentation](https://help.zend.com/zendstudio/current/content/breakpoints.htm) for Zend Studio has information on utilizing breakpoints in the debug process, however this is only to debug individual PHP classes and not applications that utilize a PHP framework.

How can I integrate Zend Studio server breakpoints into my debugging workflow for a Laravel application?

Answer (score 0):

For laravel theres couple tools that can help you debug your code, such as :

**Dump and Die**

you can use dd() to debug your code, its a feature that comes with laravel

**DebugBar**

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

With this package, you can easily track your application. You can inspect queries, messages, requests, routes, views and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, however I was not looking for additional ways to debug laravel apps. I was looking for how to specifically use Zend Studio breakpoints to analyze/debug Laravel requests.

Comment: This was not the answer I was asking for, however it does present good information for debugging Laravel apps, and you were the only one that attempted the answer so I am awarding you the bounty so it isn't wasted.